# koa-passport Authentication Always Returns 4XX

Tags: koa, koa2, koa-passport

When using **koa-passport** I am always receiving a 404 or 401 error.

```
passport.authenticate( 'local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This gave me many hours of struggle so wanted to post it here for others.)

When using **koa-passport** you must be sure to both **return** the result of the authentication, and **call authenticate with the context**.

```
return passport.authenticate( 'local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
} )( ctx );
```